# INSERT Stored procedure not working for mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create DELETE stored procedure for a mysql table. The query runs and shows that the query was successful but when I try to view the stored procedure in 'routines', it doesn't show the DELETE stored procedure. This is my code for creating the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_AccessLevel_Delete(IN id INT)                    
BEGIN                                      
    DELETE AccessLevel
    WHERE AccessLevelID = id;
END                                     
// 
DELIMITER ;
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: what "insert"? I see only a delete in there, and a delete with a syntax error at that.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that does anything with `Insert`...

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, its DELETE @MarcB

Comment: Then you should fix the delete syntax error. it's `DELETE FROM sometable ...`.

Comment: @MarcB The syntax should be fine.  The `From` is optional.  I think his issue is that he created the procedure, and now he can't find it.

Comment: @Siyual: no, it's not optional. go ahead and try to delete from a table without it.

Comment: @MarcB Ah, sorry, I'm mistaken.  I was going off `Sql Server` rather than `MySQL`. The `From` is optional there, but it looks to be required in `MySQL`.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

@siyual: putting this here since it won't fit into a comment:

```
[test]> delete foo where bar=2;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where bar=2' at line 1
[test]> delete foo;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
[test]> delete from foo;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```